# What is the easiest way to run windows cron job

Tags: windows, task, scheduler

I'm currently using windows 7 with apache, php, and mysql. I understand on windows, task scheduler is the equivalence of cron jobs on linux/unix systems. I'm wondering what the easiest way to run a php file on my localhost server is through a task scheduler. I want it to open chrome (i know how to do that) but how do I set it to go to a certain page and close once it's finished the script.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things come to mind...

One would be to utilize AutoIt which is a very powerful and public domain automation tool.  You could easily start Chrome, navigate, verify on-screen values (e.g. when your script finishes), and then close chrome.

Another alternative would be to play bit more gorilla warfare tactic and terminate the process Chrome is using after some preset amount of time has elapsed (assuming you know how long this takes to run).  See Windows' "TaskKill" command line options here: [enter link description here](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html)